# Can't save serialized array in longtext field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I am attempting to save a serialized array to a LONGTEXT field and for some reason the data is not saving and I am not getting an error.

```
    $serializeArray = serialize($result_arr) ; 
    echo "Serialized String: " . $serializeArray ."<br><br>";

    $test2 = "This is a test" ;

    $return = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE mytable.exp_cartthrob_item_options_options SET data = '" . $serializeArray ."' WHERE id = '1' " );

    echo "<br /><br />" ;
    echo $return ;
```

If I replace $serializeArray with $test it works fine.  Any ideas on whats wrong?

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: There isn't an error.  When I echo $return, it's simply blank.  With saving $test2 it's 1.

Comment: And what's your input? You can paste it here: http://pastebin.com

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, serializing data will leave in quotes and special characters, so you are likely going to be generating an invalid query with the way you are doing it. You really need to be using **prepared statement**s to ensure you will have valid queries. Not to mention you can end up with all kinds of nasty SQL injection attacks - just use prepared statements.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Second, storing serialized data in your database is generally a very poor practice since the data is no longer portable. You have a relational database with various datatypes - use them!

To highlight the risk posed by not using prepared statements, consider if the array to be serialized looked like this:

```
$resultArray = array("';DROP TABLE mytable;##");
```

Guess whats going to happen...

**Update to help:**
Here is how you would write your query using prepared statements - you will need to make sure you are validating each step to catch and handle errors.

Step 1: Write your query - the "?" is where you will bind your parameters

```
$query = "UPDATE mytable.exp_cartthrob_item_options_options SET data = ? WHERE id = '1'";
```

Step 2: Create the Prepared Statement

```
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
```

Step 3: Bind your paramters (the "?" in the query)

```
$stmt->bind_param( "s" , $serializeArray );
```

Step 4: Execute the Query

```
$stmt->execute();
```

You should ideally read through the entire *mysqli* documentation so you know what methods are available to you.

Comment: Serialized data is not always a bad thing. If you never need to query it, and it's not being manipulated very often, it's often the least bad solution for many things.

Comment: That's why I said generally ;-) This looks like it is for an item on an e-commerce site. Something that really needs to be portable if you want to be able to switch systems.

Comment: This is an ExpressionEngine add-on and the database schema is not something I have control of.

Comment: Fair enough, but you really need to be using prepared statements. That'll fix your issue here.

Comment: I've never used prepared statements before and finding the page you linked a bit confusing...

Comment: Everything you need is in the link, but nonetheless, I updated the answer so you can see exactly what you will need to do. You definitely want to read through all of the mysqli documentation and become familiar with it if you are going to be writing database driven software in PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Especially for the example, that helped tremendously. And as you stated, it fixed my issue.  Thanks again.